# Неэффективное использование оперативной памяти

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

Написал задачу на java. В ней используются postgresql, spring boot, rest. Все просто, надо считать данные из БД, объект с двумя полями айди и имя, и потом в json передать в response. Вот проверив его одной из ошибок стало неэффективное использование оперативной памяти.

Одним из условий является не использовать возможности SQL. Так же в БД по условию более миллиона записей.

Что делать чтобы исправить? Контроллер скидывать пока не буду, потому как кажется что проблема на нижних слоях, но если надо выложу сразу.

Мой код:

```
@Repository

public class ContactRepositoryImpl implements ContactRepository {


    private static final BeanPropertyRowMapper<Contact> ROW_MAPPER = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Contact.class);


    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Autowired

    public ContactRepositoryImpl(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    }


    public List<Contact> getAll() {

        System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.toString());

        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM contacts", ROW_MAPPER);

    }

}

@Service

public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {


    @Autowired

    private ContactRepository repository;


    @Override

    public List<Contact> getFilteredContacts(String nameFilter) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(nameFilter);


        List<Contact> list = repository.getAll();

        List<Contact> list2 = list.stream()

                .filter(Objects::nonNull)

                .filter(it -> it.getName() != null)

                .filter(it -> !pattern.matcher(it.getName()).matches())

                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        return list2;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял ограничения состоят в том, чтобы использовать возможности Spring Data?
Посмотрите в сторону [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html).

В данном интерфейсе есть метод:

```
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)
```

который позволяет вытягивать записи страницами.
Вы можете считывать записи постранично и мёржить результаты.

Если не хочится ломать лаконичность стримов, то можете обернуть всю логику page-инации в свой стрим, заменив list.stream() на свою реализацию [How to implement a Java stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685623/how-to-implement-a-java-stream)
.

Если лень делать ручками, можете попробовать использовать *fetch size hint*

```
@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="50"))
List<Foo> findAll();
```

[Set the fetch size with Spring Data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284503/set-the-fetch-size-with-spring-data)

Answer (score 0):

фильтрацию в getFilteredContacts можно сделать в запросе: `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND name LIKE :name`. Вы вытаскиваете все результаты из базы и гоняете туда сюда. В этом нет смысла.

Comment: Это условие. Не использовать возможности SQL.

Comment: попробуйте поставить LIMIT 5 в запросе и посмотрите будет ли утечка памяти. Если да, то проблема в этом. Смотря сколько записей у вас в contacts. По поводу условия - это странно. Ибо базовые вещи свойственные любой реляционной базе данных (если причина вдруг смигрировать на другую). и нагружать просто так базу - просто преступно :)

Comment: Ну я понимаю. Что это не логично( кстати поу словию в БД более миллиона записей.

Comment: А :name это как раз то что надо для почка совпадений? У меня просто ищется не через стандартное значение, а с помощью regex.

Comment: в итоговом виде должно быть вроде WHERE name LIKE '%Mik' (процент указывает совпадение по первым буквам). либо LIKE '%Mik%' по обоим сторонам. ну и можете использовать REGEXP (для mysql, у других свои аналоги).

Comment: К сожалению в задании так "Фильтр обязательно применять в java коде, не использовать возможности SQL.". Так что пока ответ на вопрос остаётся загадкой.

Comment: возможно имеется ввиду сделать независимым от определенной базы код. это реализует ORM.

Comment: А с чего это видно?